# JavaFX: How to pan a ScrollPane that contains Button children?

Tags: javafx, touch, mouseevent, javafx-8

In JavaFX, I have a `ScrollPane` which contains a `TilePane` which contains various `Button`s.

This application will run on a touch screen, so the user will scroll by dragging the finger through the ScrollPane, but if the finger starts dragging over a child Button, then the ScrollPane doesn't scroll. Due to the way touch UIs work today, this is unexpected behavior for the user.

I want the buttons to respond to clicks, but I want the drag events to be sent to the underlying ScrollPane instead (if it pans using the drag events).

I've set the `setPannable()` property of the `ScrollPane` to true, and I've tried to set handlers on the `Button`'s various `setOnDrag*()` methods to then fire the `ScrollPane`'s `fireEvent()` method, but nothing happened.

Example:

```
    button.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            scrollPane.fireEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm trying to do the same with mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for buttons is that the `ButtonBehavior` registers a default mapping for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED`. This mapping consumes the event and the ScrollPane does not receive it anymore for panning calculation. In previous JFX versions it was possible to simply call `ButtonSkin.consumeMouseEvents(false)` to fix that. With current versions this does not work anymore. I think this a bug and I might report it when I have time.

As a workaround I redirect the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED` to the `viewPort` of the `ScrollPane`:

```
   ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(bar)
    {
      @Override
      protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin()
      {
        Skin<?> skin = super.createDefaultSkin();
        for (Node ch : getChildren())
        {
          if (ch.getStyleClass().contains("viewport"))
            viewPort = ch;
        }
        return skin;
      }
    };
    pane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e ->
    {
      if (lastFiredEvent != e)
      {
        lastFiredEvent = e.copyFor(e.getSource(), viewPort);
        viewPort.fireEvent(lastFiredEvent);
      }
    });
```

Edit: I reported the bug. Will post the link here when it is avaiable.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8284878

Comment: beware: re-firing the event received inside an event handler might have unpredictable side-effects (because it creates a nested event dispatch)

Comment: @kleopatra would Platform.runLater help with that?

Comment: don't think so - a real solution probably (muddy waters, not much doc around and many internal classes) would be a custom event dispatcher, which hooks into the event dispatch chain (pre or post to the given)

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue with ToggleButton. Consequently, I wrote a PannableToggle class by extending from Label and implementing the Toggle interface. It's a workaround that serves my needs. However, could explore alternatives to using Label. Additionally, I believe it might be a bug, related to all input and action components.

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class PannableToggle extends Label implements javafx.scene.control.Toggle {
    private final ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroup = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final BooleanProperty             selected    = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);


    public PannableToggle() { this(null); }


    public PannableToggle(String text) {
        super(text);
        updateStyle();
        setOnMouseClicked(this::handleMouseClicked);
    }


    private void handleMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if (!isSelected() && getToggleGroup() != null) {
            getToggleGroup().selectToggle(this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        if (this.selected.get() != selected) {
            this.selected.set(selected);
            updateStyle();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() { return selected.get(); }


    @Override
    public ToggleGroup getToggleGroup() { return toggleGroup.get(); }


    @Override
    public void setToggleGroup(ToggleGroup group) {
        this.toggleGroup.set(group);
        if (group != null) {
            group.getToggles().add(this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroupProperty() { return toggleGroup; }


    @Override
    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() { return selected; }


    private void updateStyle() {
        String style = isSelected() ? " -fx-underline: true;"
            : null;
        
        setStyle(style);
    }


    // Fluent API for setting text
    public PannableToggle withText(String text) {
        setText(text);
        return this;
    }


    // Fluent API for setting toggle group
    public PannableToggle withToggleGroup(ToggleGroup group) {
        setToggleGroup(group);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this, `consume` `TouchEvent` on the `ScrollPane` such as ...

```
ScrollPane.addEventHandler(TouchEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<TouchEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TouchEvent t) { 
            t.consume();
        }
    });
```